# how can I navigate from LoginForm.js to product.js after successfull login

Tags: react-native

how to navigate from LoginForm.js to product.js ?

**route.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,View,Text } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Home from './pages/home';
import Products from './pages/product';
// import Products from './pages/components/LoginForm';

const navigation = StackNavigator({
    Home        : { screen: Home },
    // Login       : { screen: LoginForm },
    Products     : { screen: Products },
});

export default navigation;
```

**home.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, StatusBar, Image } from 'react-native';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    };

    render() {
        return ( 
        <View style = { styles.container }>
            <StatusBar
                backgroundColor="#007ac1" barStyle="light-content"/>
            <View style= { styles.logoContainer }>
              <Image style = {styles.logo} source={require('../images/logo.png')} />
            </View>

            <View style= { styles.formContainer }>
              <LoginForm />
            </View>
        </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#03a9f4'
    },
    logoContainer: {
        flexGrow: 1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'
    },
    logo: {
        width: 80, height: 80
    },
    formContainer: {

    }
});
```

**LoginForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            userName:'',
            password:'',
            type:'A'
        }

    }

    userLogin = () =>{ 
        const { userName } = this.state;
        const { password } = this.state;
        const { type }     = this.state;

        fetch('http://192.168.0.4:3000/notes',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({
                userName : userName,
                password : password,
                type     : type
            })
        })
        .then((response)=> response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    if(responseJson.response.success == true) {
                        // alert(responseJson.response.result);
                        navigate('Products');
                    }else{
                        alert(responseJson.response.result);
                    }

                })
                .catch((error)=>{
                    console.error(error);
                })   
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style = {styles.container}>
                <TextInput 
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    placeholder="Username or Email"
                    placeholderTextColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                    returnKeyType="next"
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                    onChangeText = {userName => this.setState({userName})}
                    style={styles.input} />
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder="Password"
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    secureTextEntry
                    returnKeyType="go"
                    placeholderTextColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                    ref = {(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
                    onChangeText = {password => this.setState({password})}
                    style={styles.input} />

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={this.userLogin} >
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container : {
        padding:20
    }, 
    input: {
        height:40, backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)', marginBottom:20,
        color:'#FFF', paddingHorizontal:10, borderRadius:5
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        backgroundColor: "#2980b9", paddingVertical:10, borderRadius:5
    },
    buttonText: {
        textAlign :'center', color:'#FFFFFF', fontWeight:'700'
    }
});
```

**product.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';


export default class Product extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        // title: 'Home',
        header: null
      };
    render() {
        return ( 
        <View style = { styles.container }>
            <Text> Product Page open </Text>
            <Button
                title="Go to Home"
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
            />  
        </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you please select the most relevant parts (rewrite your code if needed to target just the desired behavior while leaving out the part that you cant figure out) ... Also please read [ask]  before you make corrections

Answer (score 0):

Make `LoginForm` as part of `navigator` (it is currently commented). Then inside the `userLogin` function use `this.props.navigation.navigate('Products')` to navigate, take a look at the navigation [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating.html)

```
userLogin = () =>{ 
    ...
    fetch('http://192.168.0.4:3000/notes',{
        ...
    })
    .then((response)=> response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
         if(responseJson.response.success == true) {
             // alert(responseJson.response.result);
             this.props.navigation.navigate('Products');
         }else{
              alert(responseJson.response.result);
         }
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
         console.error(error);
    })   
}
```

Hope this will help!